# Unital $C^\ast$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ with positive elements $\mathcal{A}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, self-adjoint-operators, functional-calculus

We are given a unital $C^\ast$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ where the positive elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are defined to be self-adjoint $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\sigma(A)\subseteq[0;+\infty[$. Denoting the collection of positive elements $\mathcal{A}_+$ and set $\mathcal{A}_-=\{A|-A\in\mathcal{A}_+\}$.

In the following I want to show that $\mathcal{A}_{-} \cap \mathcal{A}_{+}=\{0\}$.

---

**Idea:** We have $\sigma(A)\subseteq[0;+\infty[$ and also $\sigma(-A)\subseteq[0;+\infty[$. Now this implies that $\sigma(A)=\{0\}$ which holds if $A=0$ and therefore one can conclude that $\mathcal{A}_+\cap\mathcal{A}_-=\{0\}$.

---

Am I on the right track? If no, then how can one actually show $\mathcal{A}_{-} \cap \mathcal{A}_{+}=\{0\}$?

Comment: The self-adjointness is necessary, otherwise $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ would be a counterexample. On the other hand, for matrices, a self-adjoint matrix has an orthonormal basis of eigenvalues. If $\sigma(A)=\{0\}$ for such a matrix, all eigenvalues are zero, and $A$ is the zero matrix, as desired. Of course, this doesn't cover the full generality you want.

Comment: Hi user, thank you for your comment. I see that it would be a counter-example regarding the self-adjoint. However is my calculations correct? I mean, did I actually show $\mathcal{A}_{-} \cap \mathcal{A}_{+}=\{0\}$? In my world I did but I want others to see if I am on the right track.

Comment: Yes. Everything you've written is correct. I was just thinking out loud about where to go next.

Comment: Ah excellent! I am glad that it is correct. Is there other approach to show it instead of what I did?

Comment: To clarify my previous remarks What you have written is correct, but I would say not entirely complete. You have correctly shown that $A\in \mathcal{A}_-\cap \mathcal{A}_+$ must satisfy $\sigma(A)=\{0\}$, Then you have written this holds if $A=0$. What you want to say at this point is that for a self-adjoint $A$, $\sigma(A)=\{0\}$ holds **if and only if** $A=0$. This is where self-adjointness is needed, since $\|A\|$ is the spectral radius for a self-adjoint $A$. This shows that $\mathcal{A}_+\cap \mathcal{A}_-\subset \{0\}$. Of course, $\mathcal{A}_+\cap \mathcal{A}_-\supset \{0\}$.

Comment: If there is a different approach, I wouldn't want to see it. Your approach is about as short and sweet as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

You have reduced the problem to showing that if $A$ is selfadjoint and $\sigma(A)=\{0\}$, then $A=0$. This can be done in several ways, depending on what tools you have available. Here are a couple.

- From Banach algebra theory one can show that the spectral radius of $A$ is $\lim_n\|A^n\|^{1/n}$. In the particular case where $A=A^*$, it is not too hard to show that this limit is $\|A\|$.
- If you have the Gelfand transform available, then you know that $C^*(A)\simeq C(\sigma(A))=C(\{0\})=\mathbb C$, and the isomorphism takes $A$ to the identity function $t\longmapsto t$ on the set $\{0\}$, which is the zero function.

Comment: Thank you, Martin! I will try to do so.